# ERROR [4/5] COPY puppeteer-latest.tgz /home/pptruser/puppeteer-latest.tgz

Tags: puppeteer

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile

### => ERROR [4/5] COPY puppeteer-latest.tgz /home/pptruser/puppeteer-latest.tgz                   0.0s

> [4/5] COPY puppeteer-latest.tgz /home/pptruser/puppeteer-latest.tgz:

---

failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/puppeteer-latest.tgz" not found: not found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.